# CDN images are getting displayed but CDN domain throwing access denied error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

This is with respect to AWS Cloudfront. We are trying to configure CloudFront as CDN.

We have created a CDN distribution which is cdn.mywebdomain.com and is pointing to S3 bucket.

on browser, cdn.mywebdomain.com is throwing Access Denied but if i put the full path viz. https://cdn.mywebdomain.com/imagefolder1/image1.jpg it shows the correct image.

How do i solve the access denied issue?

Comment: Did you specify `Default Root Object` in your CF?

Comment: The link you posted says the certificate expired (10/18/2017).

Comment: @AllanWind , the above is example link. we have it in same format. It is masked.

Comment: @Marcin, No i have not configured Default Root Object. , it "-"

Comment: Have you tried setting it up? Usually you would use `index.html` of whatever is your root file.

Comment: @Marcin, we are only hosting images there.

Comment: If you use `cdn.mywebdomain.com` then what image it should point to?

Comment: @Marcin, understood. I am trying to setup CDN on woocommerce. So basically, i will create one dummy object "index.html" and try it out. should i set it as default root object? Or can i put any image as default root object

Comment: Anything should be fine. But if you don't really need it, why do you have to use plain `cdn.mywebdomain.com`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228559/discussion-between-dongoo-and-marcin).